# How to download, compile and link a library as external project in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to use the `ExternalProject_Add` framework in CMake to automatically download, compile and link a static library. You can find the library [here](https://github.com/OSSystems/inih), however the question can be applied to any external CMake project.

Here are the boundary conditions of my question:

1. The **external project is CMake compatible**
2. The external project provides a static or dynamic library to be linked to a target of the main project
3. The ExternalProject_Add framework is to be used
4. UNIX (Linux and MacOS) portability is enough
5. Modern CMake is available (CMake 3.14+)

I was able to get it working by hardcoding a lot of stuff, but I am pretty positive that my solution is not elegant or portable.

Here is my project structure

```
root
|---> CMakeList.txt
|
|---> external ---> CMakeList.txt
|              |--> CMakeList.txt.inih.in     
|
|--->   src    ---> CMakeList.txt
```

`root/CMakeList.txt`

```
add_subdirectory(external)
set(INIH_LIB_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/inih-install/lib)
set(INIH_INC_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/inih-install/include/inih)
set(INIH_LIBRARIES inih inihcpp)
message(STATUS "inih includes directory : ${INIH_LIB_DIR}")
message(STATUS "inih libraries directory : ${INIH_INC_DIR}")
add_subdirectory(src)
```

`root/external/CMakeList.txt`

```
configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/external/CMakeLists.txt.inih.in inih-download/CMakeLists.txt)
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G "${CMAKE_GENERATOR}" .
        RESULT_VARIABLE result
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/inih-download)
if (result)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake step for inih failed: ${result}")
endif ()
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build .
        RESULT_VARIABLE result
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/inih-download)
if (result)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Build step for inih failed: ${result}")
endif ()
```

`root/external/CMakeList.txt.inih.in`

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(inih
        GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/OSSystems/inih.git
        GIT_TAG           master
        SOURCE_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/inih-src"
        BINARY_DIR        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/inih-build"
        INSTALL_DIR       "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/inih-install"
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/inih-install ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/inih-src
        BUILD_COMMAND     ${MAKE}
        INSTALL_COMMAND   make install
        TEST_COMMAND      ""
        )
```

`root/src/CMakeList.txt`

```
add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_include_directories(test PRIVATE ${INIH_INC_DIR})
target_link_directories(test PRIVATE ${INIH_LIB_DIR})
target_link_libraries(WagasciRecon ${INIH_LIBRARIES})
```

My question is: **Is there a more elegant and portable way to achieve this?**

Comment: If you want the external library to be built as part of your own build process anyway, maybe it will be enough to just include it as a git submodule to your source tree and then use add_subdirectory?

Comment: The approach (`configure_file`, `execute_process`, `ExternalProject_Add`) is viable. Some lines could be *improved*. E.g. instead of `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` you could use `CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<INSTALL_DIR>`, where `<INSTALL_DIR>` is *literal*: `ExternalProject_Add` automatically expands it to the appropriate path. You may also omit specification of `SOURCE_DIR` and `BINARY_DIR`, because the main project doesn't depend from them.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you for the hints. They worked perfectly. Bacause of DRY, I am trying to use `ExternalProject_Get_Property(inih install_dir)` in the `root/CMakeList.txt` file, but I persistently get the error `get_property could not find TARGET inih.  Perhaps it has not yet been created.`. Am I missing something?

Comment: The CMake **subproject** built by `execute_process` is NOT a part of your **main** CMake project. So the target `inih` created in the subproject is not visible to the main project. That is, if you want to specify installation directory for external project only once, then this specification should be performed in the **main** project, and somehow passed to the subproject. E.g. in the main project you may have `set(INIH_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/inih-install)` and in `root/external/CMakeList.txt.inih.in` specify `INSTALL_DIR ${INIH_INSTALL_DIR})`.

Comment: Well, actually there is something strange in your approach. Combination of `execute_process` and `ExternalProject_Add` called inside it, is usually used when you want to use `find_package()` for the subproject. This is because `find_package` requires **subproject** to be already **installed** when the **main** project is **configured**. Otherwise, the main project could directory call `ExternalProject_Add`. This way a **subproject** will be **installed** at the **build** stage of the **main** project.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You are right once again. I have set the `INIH_INSTALL_DIR` and all the other variables in the top CMakeList.txt file and I have removed the `execute_process` calls. The most important modification was to add the inih project as a dependency to the main target through `add_dependency`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from Tsyvarev, I was able to achieve the same goal with a much cleaner and more robust code:

- `root/CMakeList.txt`

```
set(INIH_PROJECT inih_project)
set(INIH_INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/inih-install)
set(INIH_LIB_DIR ${INIH_INSTALL_DIR}/lib)
set(INIH_INC_DIR ${INIH_INSTALL_DIR}/include/inih)

add_library (inih STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties (inih PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${INIH_LIB_DIR}/libinih.a)
target_include_directories(inih INTERFACE ${INIH_INC_DIR})

add_library (inihcpp STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(inihcpp PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${INIH_LIB_DIR}/libinihcpp.a)
target_include_directories(inihcpp INTERFACE ${INIH_INC_DIR})

set(INIH_LIBRARIES inih inihcpp)
message(STATUS "inih includes directory : ${INIH_INC_DIR}")
message(STATUS "inih libraries directory : ${INIH_LIB_DIR}")

...

add_subdirectory(external)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

- `root/external/CMakeList.txt`

```
include(CMakeLists.txt.inih.in)
```

- `root/external/CMakeList.txt.inih.in`

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(${INIH_PROJECT}
        GIT_REPOSITORY    https://github.com/OSSystems/inih.git
        GIT_TAG           master
        PREFIX            "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/inih-prefix"
        INSTALL_DIR       "${INIH_INSTALL_DIR}"
        CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<INSTALL_DIR>
        BUILD_COMMAND     ${MAKE}
        INSTALL_COMMAND   make install
        TEST_COMMAND      ""
        )
```

- `root/src/CMakeList.txt`

```
add_executable(test test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test ${INIH_LIBRARIES})
```

**UPDATE**

If you apply the above solution to a fresh build directory you will stumble on an error like `Imported target "inih" includes non-existent path`, that can be worked around as shown [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/15052)

Comment: You may move the whole information about `inih_project` into `inih` and `inihcpp` IMPORTED **targets**: `target_include_directories` (but replace PRIVATE with INTERFACE), `target_link_directories` (while it is not needed since you specify absolute paths to the libraries), and even `add_dependencies`. So `root/src/CMakeList.txt` could contain just 2 lines: `add_executable(test test.cpp)` and `target_link_libraries(test ${INIH_LIBRARIES})`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev And that is true indeed. Thank you again. I have edited the answer accordingly.